# How to modify root element with javascript

Tags: javascript

I have got a question.
How to change `font-size` of `:root`, using javascript?
I need to make a button to resize font in a whole website.

Comment: You mean changing the stylesheet rules ?

Comment: Root means `body` or `html`

Comment: Or as in a CSS variable? Like `:root { --font-size: 16px; }`

Comment: Also see possible duplicate at https://stackoverflow.com/a/33598560/2177147

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I have no idea what `--font-size` should be, accessing `:root` itself seems to be working with [`CSSStyleSheet.insertRule()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleSheet/insertRule)

```js
function doThing(){
  document.styleSheets[0].insertRule(':root { font-size: 26px; }');
}
```

```html
HelloWord<br>
<button onclick="doThing()">Clicky</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you change the `document.body.style.fontSize` you are basically changing the `:root`. As long as the rest of your styles use `em` or `rem` font-sizes, all the text on the site should change accordingly.